# Schematron / preceding-sibling and following-sibling are the same element

Tags: schematron

Desperately trying to get Schematron to alert only if the EFFECT element resides between two SUBTASK elements - they are siblings to each other. Greatly appreciate any assistance and please let me know if more information is needed.

Here is some simple sample code:

```
<TOPIC>
 <SUBTASK></SUBTASK>
 <EFFECT></EFFECT>
 <SUBTASK></SUBTASK>
</TOPIC>
```

Here are two of my Schematron attempts - the problem is its alerting on every EFFECT within the document instead of just between the two SUBTASK. *note - EFFECT is a wildcard and allowed everywhere.

```
<rule context="EFFECT">
 <assert test="preceding-sibling::*[position()[1]][SUBTASK] = following-sibling::*[position()[1]][SUBTASK]" role="error" id="error_EFFECT_between_SUBTASK" 
   >EFFECT not allowed between two SUBTASKs</assert>
</rule>

<rule context="EFFECT">
 <assert test="count(preceding-sibling::*[position()>0]) and preceding-sibling::*[position()[1]][SUBTASK] = following-sibling::*[position()[1]][SUBTASK]" role="error" id="error_EFFECT_between_SUBTASKs" 
  >EFFECT not allowed between two SUBTASK</assert>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had most of the pieces, but lacked `self::` for the 'self' axis.  Try (untested):

```xml
<rule context="EFFECT">
 <assert test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::SUBTASK] and
               following-sibling::*[1][self::SUBTASK]"
         role="error" id="error_EFFECT_between_SUBTASKs" 
  >EFFECT not allowed between two SUBTASK</assert>
</rule>
```

`[SUBTASK]` is true if there is a `SUBTASK` child, not if the context element is a `SUBTASK`.

`[position()[1]]` would probably be an error is XPath 1.0, but in XPath 2.0 or XPath 3.0, it would be true every time because `position()` returns a non-zero number, and the `[1]` reduces the singe-item sequence of numbers to the first (and only) number in the sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at this!  Your query (though still alerting on all the EFFECT) made me think I needed to micromanaged this alert a little more.  Because all the SUBTASK are located within a TOPIC this seems working. Know I removed SELF - but it 'seems' to be hitting correctly?        
 <rule context="TOPIC/EFFECT">
      <assert test="preceding-sibling::*[1][SUBTASK] and following-sibling::*[1][SUBTASK]" 
               role="error" id="error_EFFECT_between_SUBTASKs" 
        >EFFECT not allowed between two SUBTASK</assert>
    </rule>